# Authenticating an SVN location within Maven <plugin>

Tags: maven, svn, maven-3

In changing a SVN repo to not allow for 'anonymous' access, two components in our maven build are now failing when trying to read two files from SVN.

This is because we now need to authenticate to read from the repositories. How would I add SVN credentials to the below Maven snippet / is there an alternative way to declare the below repo's with their respective authentication details?

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                        <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                        <excludeFilterFile>http://somesubversionrepository/findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <targetJdk>1.5</targetJdk>
                        <minimumPriority>2</minimumPriority>
                        <rulesets>
                            <ruleset>http://somesubversionrepository/RuleSet.xml</ruleset>
                        </rulesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: Aren't the pmd rulesets simple a list of rules but not an url ?

Comment: Yes - but we keep ours in SVN to be used across different projects

Comment: As far as i know this is not supported to authenticate against an http url in this case. To keep them consistent across the projects i would suggest to put them into a company pom which contains such kind of configuration which can be done in findbugs-maven-plugin (multi module setup externalize them). But not that i know in maven-pmd-plugin (but might worth to file in [jira as an improvement](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MPMD)).

Comment: Great thank you very much for the comment! I will take your advice given above in the mean time - + raise JIRA.

Comment: JIRA Raised in PMD at link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MPMD-210